# update source trigger of one control should effect the other control

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, updatesourcetrigger

I am using a third party control for datagrid. I have implemented property changed event in model class and it is working when i use

```
 Text="{Binding itemQty, UpdateSourceTrigger=propertychanged}"
```

it is even updating in my data source, but i have another textbox here data is not retrieving from the item source though item source is updated with new values.
I want to display the data with property changed event of first textbox and the rows are dynamic, so i can't directly call them.
If i refresh the data source it is displaying but i can't use that process as it is time taking process when items are many.

Comment: If the answer has resolved your issue please [mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) it as accepted to convenient people who visit this thread later, Thanks for understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to display the data with property changed event of first textbox and the rows are dynamic

The problem is you have not set `Mode=TwoWay` for your `Text` property. And [`UpdateSourceTrigger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.updatesourcetrigger) defines constants that indicate when a binding source is updated by its binding target in **two-way** binding.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Info,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding Info}"/>
```

**Code behind**

```
private string info { get; set; }
public string Info
{
    get { return info; }
    set
    {
        info = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string properName = null)
{
    if(PropertyChanged != null)
    this.PropertyChanged(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs(properName));
}
```